# maximum , minimum value of $f(x)= -x+\sqrt{x-2}+2\sqrt{x-1}$

Tags: functions

maximum and minimum value of

$f(x)= -x+\sqrt{x-2}+2\sqrt{x-1}$

what i try

function is valid for $x\geq 2$

$\displaystyle f'(x) = -1+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x-2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{x-1}}$

and $\displaystyle f''(x) = -\frac{1}{4}(x-2)^{-\frac{3}{2}}-\frac{1}{2}(x-1)^{-\frac{3}{2}}$

how do i solve it help me please

Comment: Have you tried setting the derivative to $0$? And have you considered what happens to $f(x)$ as $x\to \infty$?

Comment: @ Minus One-Twelfth not find and good value of $x$ while setting $f'(x)=0$

Answer (score 1):

The domain of $f$ is the set $D=[2, +\infty[$ and the max/min can occur in interior points $x^*$ where $f'(x^*)=0$ or $f$ is not differentiable, or in the boundary of $D$.

Since $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to +\infty}f(x)=-\infty$, $f$ does not have a global minimum.

Since $f' > 0$ close to $x=2$, this boundary point will be a local minimum.

Since $f$ is strictly concave in $D$ and there is a point $x^* \in D$ such that $f'(x^*)=0$, this point is the unique global maximum. ($x^* \approx 2.66609$)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use some software to find the root of the equation $f'(x) = 0$.
First, the function is defined as $x> 2$ and $f '(x)> 0$ for $x$ values close to $2$. Then the continuous function is increasing close to $2$, but it will be at some point decreasing since $lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}  f(x) = - \infty$.

Then we will have a local maximum point (which will be global) and we will have no minimum point.
One idea is to check the graph of the function:
[image]

Now, on the calculations of the equation $f' (x) = 0$, we have algebraically and manipulating the accounts we arrive at

$$
f'(x) = -1 + \dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{x-2}}+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x-1}}=0 \iff 
\dfrac{\sqrt{x-1}+2\sqrt{x-2}}{2\sqrt{x-2}\sqrt{x-1}}=1 \iff
4\sqrt{x^2 -3x+2} = 4x^2 -17x+17.
$$
If you continues, have
$$
f'(x) = 0 \Rightarrow 16x^4 +273x^2 -394x+121=0.
$$
which does not have an immediate analytical solution. So I guess you should use calculator or some software to calculate the root.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from @Thiago Alexandre's answer, looking at the plot, you can see that the maximum is close to $3.5$.

You can make it better using a second order Taylor expansion around this value and get
$$f(x)=\left(\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}+\sqrt{10}-\frac{7}{2}\right)+\left(\sqrt{\frac{2}{5}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}-1\right)
   \left(x-\frac{7}{2}\right)-\left(\frac{1}{6 \sqrt{6}}+\frac{1}{5 \sqrt{10}}\right)
   \left(x-\frac{7}{2}\right)^2+O\left(\left(x-\frac{7}{2}\right)^3\right)$$ Ignore the higher order terms, compute the derivative and make it equal to zero. This would give, after some messy simplications of the radicals
$$x_*=\frac{17}{2}-\frac{5}{17} \left(2+3 \sqrt{6}\right) \left(25-6 \sqrt{15}\right)\approx 3.65502$$ Now, compute $f(x_*)$ to get $ \approx 0.890302$.

The exact values would be $x_*=3.66524$ and $f(x_*)=0.890314$. This is quite close at the price of a (nasty) quadratic equation.